# how to add a delimiter (,) at various places in a line and write to a text file in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my sample input file data

> 0067011990999991950051507004+68750+023550FM-12+038299999V0203301N00671220001CN9999999N9+00001+99999999999
>
> 0043011990999991950051512004+68750+023550FM-12+038299999V0203201N00671220001CN9999999N9+00221+99999999999

I'm trying to delimit at specific lengths in a line to save in various columns in a db table. Below is the sample output.

> 0067,011990,99999,19500515,0700,4,+68750,+023550,FM-12,+0382,99999,V020,330,1,N,0067,1,2,20001,C,N,999999,9,N,9,+0000,1,+9999,9,99999,9

**Code**

```
with open('data1.txt', 'w', encoding='latin_1') as output:
    with open('data.txt', 'r', encoding='latin_1') as input:
        for line in input:
            nline = line+','
            output.write(nline)
```

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: What logic are you using to determine where you want delimiter placed? Every n characters?

Comment: why has this question been downvoted and has so many close votes?

Comment: @Anil_M Delimiting is at fixed places, it translates to some codes. i just need to insert it in a database, so looking for some code to do that as i have many such files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is fixed-width delimited, I'd probably write a generator that took a series of character-widths and outputted a comma between each one. Though honestly that's more because it's more *obviously correct* than efficient.

```
def add_commas(s, widths):
    ss = iter(s)
    for w in widths:
        for _ in range(w):
            try:
                yield next(ss)
            except StopIteration:
                return
        yield ","
    yield from ss

''.join(add_commas("this is really long", [4, 3, 5]))
# 'this, is, real,ly long'
```

If you like, wrap this in a function that outputs the string directly

```
from functools import wraps

def output_str(wrapped):
    @wraps(wrapped)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return ''.join(wrapped(*args, **kwargs))
    return wrapper

@output_str
def add_commas(s, widths):  # as above...
    ss = iter(s)
    for w in widths:
        for _ in range(w):
            try:
                yield next(ss)
            except StopIteration:
                return
        yield ","
    yield from ss

add_commas("this is really long", [4, 3, 5])
```

Comment: its fixed width delimited. I think your idea should work. Let me try and update here.

Comment: Got it working with the help of your functions. Thanks a ton (y) . Posting code below

Answer (score 0):

How about this?
We insert the commas in reverse order:

```
string = "0043011990999991950051512004+68750+023550FM-12+038299999V0203201N00671220001CN9999999N9+00221+99999999999"
lst = list(string)
delimiters = [1,7,9,10]

for item in delimiters[::-1]:
    lst.insert(item,",")

''.join(lst)
```

or as a function

```
string = "0043011990999991950051512004+68750+023550FM-12+038299999V0203201N00671220001CN9999999N9+00221+99999999999"
delimiters = [1,7,9,10]

def add_delimiters(string):
    lst = list(string) 
    for item in delimiters[::-1]:
        lst.insert(item,",")
    return ''.join(lst)

add_delimiters(string)
```

Comment: I tried this too, but I'm not getting the desired output                                            with open('data.txt', 'r', encoding='latin_1') as input:
        for string in input:
            new_line = add_delimiters(string)                                                                                --This is the output I'm getting---       0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,04,3,0,12650999991949032418004+62300+010750FM-12+048599999V0202701N00461220001CN0500001N9+00781+99999999999

Answer (score -1):

```
from functools import wraps

def output_str(wrapped):
    @wraps(wrapped)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return ''.join(wrapped(*args, **kwargs))
    return wrapper

@output_str
def add_commas(s, widths):  # as above...
    ss = iter(s)
    for w in widths:
        for _ in range(w):
            try:
                yield next(ss)
            except StopIteration:
                return
        yield ","
    yield from ss



with open('data1.txt', 'w', encoding='latin_1') as output:
    with open('data.txt', 'r', encoding='latin_1') as input:
        for line in input:
            new_line = add_commas(line, [4, 6, 5, 8,4,1,6,7,5,5,5,4,3,1,1,4,1,1,5,1,1,6,1,1,1,5,1,5,1,5])
            print (new_line)
            output.write(new_line)


    input.close()
output.close()
```